# Unity Button Text Change

Tags: function, user-interface, button, text, unity-game-engine

How do I change the text in a button with a variable?

```
import UnityEngine.UI;

var Answer_1 = (readData[2]);
A_1.GetComponentsInChildren<Text>().text = Answer_1;
```

And how do you start a function when the button is clicked without having to create the button in the script?

```
A_1.onClick.AddListener(markQuestion(id));                  
// ^^^ and how do I make the function start when the button is clicked
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To "start a function when the button is clicked" you can use the new UI EventSystem. 
Select the button on the hierarchy and in the inspector, in the Button(Script) component : 
- Click on the "+"
- Add your GameObject containing your script
- And finally, you can select your function among the functions in the script